# Getting an error when calling createuser of Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting this error

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.client.Firebase.createUser(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.firebase.client.Firebase$ValueResultHandler)' on a null object reference
            at com.test.test2.myfirebasetest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)

Can you please tell my what I am doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView email, pass;
    Firebase myFirebaseRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);
        signin.setOnClickListener(this);
        Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(**LINK**);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.register:
                myFirebaseRef.createUser(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString(), new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                        //do something
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        // there was an error
                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.signin:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I re-declared myFirebaseRef, so the onclick was using the global variable which was not initialized yet.